# Literature for representation for boolean functions

Tags: boolean-functions, survey

What is the standard literary reading to understand:

$1)$ polynomial(including minimal) representation of boolean functions?

$2)$ polynomial(including minimal) approximation of boolean functions?

$3)$ rational(including minimal) representation of boolean functions?

$4)$ rational(including minimal) approximation of boolean functions?

Comment: Did you look at the book Yuval recommended?

Comment: I could not find it in the library. I have ordered Interlibrary loan. Waiting for the book. I thought I could find something else in the meanwhile. Also since I have not seen the book, 1) I was wondering if there would be explicit examples somewhere 2) also from the answers I am receiving, I am unsure if rational functions would be touched anywhere.

Comment: Is this the book you are looking for? http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/

Comment: @SashoNikolov yes. I went here http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~ryanod/?page_id=2334 and coukld not find online to download.

Comment: You can read all of it online in the meantime.